# How to take records from one table based on condition in second table connected by join table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables `Clients` and `Accounts`. Each client may have several accounts and one account may be related with more than one client (in certain cases) so I have third table `Clients_Accounts` which is an ordinary join table so the relevant part is :

```
Clients   |   Accounts                 |  Clients_Accounts
Id(PK)    |   Id(PK); Amount(int)      |  Id(PK); ClientId(FK); AccountId(FK)
```

I'm stuck on how to select data from `Clients` depending on the amount that they have in their `Accouts`. For example all `Clients` where `Amount >= 5000`.

I know the basics of `JOIN` so I can get somewhere near here:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Clients AS c
INNER JOIN Clients_Accounts AS cs ON c.Id = cs.ClientId
```

And here is where I get lost since I want to get the amount associated with the `AccountId` foreign key and check it if it meet the condition so that I get only those `ClientId's` associated with `AccountId's` with amount larger than `5000` and then, eventually use those `ID's` to finally select the `Client's` data from the `Clients` table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you try this?

```
 SELECT * FROM Clients C
 JOIN Clients_Accounts CS
 ON c.Id = cs.ClientId
 JOIN Accounts A
 ON A.Id = cs.AccountId
 WHERE A.Amount > 5000
```

It's basically a + level of join including the accounts' ID (in both tables).
This should be the **base** of what you need, however because of the many to many relationships, you might have to `GROUP` it to get a cumulative total of an account that shows up at multiple clients.

The grouping I've mentioned would look something like this, assuming I've understood your OP correctly (which I am not sure, since I haven't got any coffee yet)

```
 SELECT c.id, SUM(a.amount) FROM Clients C
 JOIN Clients_Accounts CS
 ON c.Id = cs.ClientId
 JOIN Accounts A
 ON A.Id = cs.AccountId
 GROUP BY c.id, a.id
 HAVING SUM(a.amount) > 5000
```

I hope this will help! :)

Comment: Thanks, it's working too. Appreciate the effort to write some additional code.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm missing something in your requirements, but if you want to get a list of clients that have accounts with amount >= 5000 then this should do it:

```
SELECT * FROM Clients AS c
INNER JOIN Clients_Accounts AS cs
ON c.Id = cs.ClientId
INNER JOIN Accounts a 
ON a.Id = cs.AccountId
WHERE a.Amount >= 5000
```

Of course this list might include clients that have accounts with less than 5000 too as long as they have at least one account with >= 5000. If you want clients with a total sum over all associated accounts >= 5000 then you would have to use an aggregate function with a `group by` and `having` clause.

Comment: Thanks, it's working. I'm always gald when additional advices are given, it's very helpful!